# How do I convert string hex representation to byte ? - javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

My problem consists of stream of bytes or array of bytes. 
This is no problem with these

```
'\u0000'
'\u0000'
'\u0001'
'\u0010'
```

But the problem lies when i decode some special characters as this

```
'\u0000'
'\u0000'
'\u0000'
'�'
```

from right to left(or here bottom to top) i can get the numeric value of these 4 bytes to 1 integer or number. but I dont know if this is correct

```
toInt (buff){
    console.log('buff ' , typeof buff[0]);
    for(let b of buff){
        console.log('b' , b);
    }
    return (buff[3] & 0x000000ff  )  |
        (buff[2] & 0x0000ff00  ) << 8  |
        (buff[1] & 0x00ff0000 ) << 16  |
        (buff[0] & 0xff000000 ) << 24 ;
}
```

Comment: I'm 99& sure you missed the `function` keyword

Comment: @Bálint are u sure i need a function keyword? cause i can call my function toInt without it.

Comment: I'm 100 % sure in it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood your question correctly but sounds like you want to convert an array of strings which represent hex bytes into a number.

If you've got a string representation of hex numbers you could convert them using something like:

```
function bufferToInt(buff) {
    var string = buff.join('');
    return parseInt(string, 16); // parseInt allows specifying a base
}

bufferToInput(['ff', 'ff']); // This returns 65535
```

Assuming each element in buff contained a string representation of a hex byte such as "ff" the above should allow simple conversion to an number using mainly built in functions.